# Copying folder contents to another folder with Automation Anywhere

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I'm aiming to move the contents of my downloads folder after running the automated process of downloading around 1000 phonecalls (long story but the BT archiving tool doesn't work and they aren't responding to our emails about *why* it's not working.

I have created a custom folder variable (just a fancy version of the date variable) and so the robot will create the folder as this bot runs on the same day every week.

I'm unable to transfer all the downloads from the downloads folder using the keystroke options oddly... I can use "CTRL+a", "CTRL + x" but "CTRL + v" doesn't want to work once the folder is open and has been made the active window...

Any suggestions on how to move all these files? the downloaded files are actually .zip folders so I can't use the "Copy files" function.

Comment: Just to be clear; are you trying to open the zip file and copy the files inside of it? Or are you trying to copy the zip itself?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use the copy folder option? You just pass in the source folder and the destination. You can use a wildcard here if needed as well. You could loop over "Each Folder in a Folder" and run your source as `\\locationhere\*.zip`

Likewise if that's not what you're trying to do, you can run the same loop using "Unzip Files" passing the source zip and destination folder of the files inside it.

[image: AA Files Folders]

Answer (score 0):

Start Loop "Each File In Folder <>"
  Unzip Files <>
  Extract Zip File to Folder <>
End Loop
Now you can use the Loop each file in a folder and copy to another folder.